# TFS 2010 Builds got invisible in contributors of some project in a project collection?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

Builds visibility is invisible after some days of work in TFS2010. When we restart the app tier server it again starts working. Issue is unknown. Once there was an error of maximum pool connections are utilized. so now i cannot see that error but there is an issue which i am not able to figure out.

How can i resolve this issue. Setup is Data tier (server1) , app tier (server2) and build server (server3).
I have tried to find the issue, but there are no such exceptions in the event viewer. Administrators can view the builds in vS2012 but they also cannot queue the build. whereas the contributors group were not able to see the builds at all which they used to see it.

this is the error which i see most in TFS Apptier eventviewer. This error eventlog is exists for almost everyday.

TFS 3010 : 
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.